# Versioning the CMIS metadata

Tags: cmis, apache-chemistry

I am using the standard CMIS from Apache Chemistry and I want to know if there is any way to version the metadata of the documents and folders. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

From the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/csprd01/CMIS-v1.1-csprd01.html):

> CMIS supports versioning of document objects. **Folder objects**, relationship objects, policy objects, and item objects **cannot be versioned**

When it comes to Documents, you can indeed version their metadata using the [checkin method](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/csprd01/CMIS-v1.1-csprd01.html#x1-990004). In the Chemistry Java client you would do something like:

```
Document doc   = (Document) session.getObject(docId);
ObjectId pwcId = document.checkOut();
Document pwc   = (Document) getSession(CONTENT_REPOSITORY).getObject(pwcId);

Map<String, Object> newProps = alterProperties(pwc);    // updated props
ContentStream newStream      = alterContentStream(pwc); // updates stream, if you need
ObjectId newId               = pwc.checkIn(true, newProps, newStream, "Checkin message");
```

In the above `newId` will be the object ID of a new version containing the new properties you set.